# How to get new-value without changing old-value of next aspect-node?

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I have this type:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedAspect]
public class MyDataModel
{
    ...
    [OnSetAspect("OnSelectedUserChanged")]
    public string SelectedUser { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

On which I apply these aspects: per-class aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class NotifyPropertyChangedAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    ...
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var newValue = args.Value;
        var oldValue = args.GetCurrentValue();
        args.ProceedSetValue();
        //base.OnSetValue(args); // same effect of ProceedSetValue()
        ... /* some more stuff... */ ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and per-field aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class OnSetAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    ...
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var newValue = args.Value;
        var oldValue = args.GetCurrentValue();
        args.ProceedSetValue();
        //base.OnSetValue(args); // same effect of ProceedSetValue()
        ... /* some more stuff... */ ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now what happens is that `NotifyPropertyChangedAspect.OnSetValue(...)` is called, and when it calls `args.GetCurrentValue()`, the `args.Value` changes its value (as a result of the next node in the aspects binding, I guess) so when `OnSetAspect.OnSetValue(...)` is called, the `args.Value` is no longer valid.

Both these aspects should check previous value and new value (meaning the value about to be set) and do something accordingly.

They don't change the value to be set, so they are not supposed to influence on each other, but they do...

How can I make these two aspects untangled ?

Answer (score 0):

The misconception here is that when you specify aspect attribute on a class, it is not applied to that class, but multicasted on that class. Multicasting is a mechanism which applies the attribute (not aspect!) recursively to all contained declarations or even on derived declarations. See [PostSharp documentation on this matter](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-conceptual).

The declaration on which the aspect is really applied is the one that matches aspect's level. There are following basic aspect levels:

- AssemblyLevelAspect
- TypeLevelAspect
- InstanceLevelAspect
- MethodLevelAspect
- LocationLevelAspect
- FieldLevelAspect
- EventLevelAspect

Aspect's runtime instance then exists once per entity. I.e. in your case there is one singleton aspect instance per location.

In your case, you are applying a LocationLevelAspect to a class, which makes the aspect to be multicasted on all fields and so you end up having two LocationInterceptionAspects on every field/property.

`args.GetCurrentValue()` fetches value of the underlying property, but should not change `args.Value`, which has the same semantic as `value` parameter in property setter.

Therefore aspects are not really tangled, they are applied in order (which you can specify). And always wrap the previous one completely.